# how to hide reply-to header when received by mail box?

Tags: php

How can i hide reply to header , from mail boxes, 
For example , i send a mail from test@domain.com with reply to as notification@domain.com, and receiver open the mail and click on reply, i want the receiver to see from email which is test@domain.com in reply, instead of reply to which is  notification@domain.com, and also the reply will come  notification@domain.com .

Any help. My code below

```html
<?php
if(@isset($_POST['send'])){
$From  = $_POST['From'];
$Subject = $_POST['Name'];
//$Message = $_POST['Message'];


$Message = "";
$Reply= "notification@domain.com";
 



$Emails = $_POST['Emails'];
$toname = $_POST['toname'];
$Name  = $_POST['Name'];
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ".$Reply."\r\n";
$headers .= "From: ".$From."\r\n";
$headers .= "Hi<br>".$toname."\r\n";
$headers .= "<br><br>Are you today? <br><br><br><br>Thanks,<br>".$Name."<br><br>
Sent from my work office\r\n";

$Emails = explode("\r\n", $_POST['Emails']);
foreach($Emails as $email) {
mail($email,$Subject,$Message,$headers);
echo "<br>Sending Email from : name:".$Name.", email: ".$From.", to name: ".$toname.", email:".$email." => was successfully sent";
//echo "<br>Sending Email To : ".$email." => Done";
}
}
?>
```